# textfield validation for password and email

Tags: swift3

I want to implement the textfield validation for two textfielfd separately but I m unable to do so I have uplide delegates for both but they get applied for both the text fields for eg. email accepts only 10 chars how can we apply it separately for both email and mobile no separately Here is the code I have written:

```
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {
        if textField == textfieldemail
                {
                    let providedEmailAddress = self.textfieldemail.text

                    let isEmailAddressValid = isValidEmailAddress(emailAddressString: providedEmailAddress!)

                    if isEmailAddressValid
                    {
                        print("Email address is valid")
                    }
                    else {

                        self.displayAlertMessage(messageToDisplay: "Email address is not valid")

                        }
                }
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let charsLimit = 10

    let startingLength = textField.text?.characters.count ?? 0
    let lengthToAdd = string.characters.count
    let lengthToReplace =  range.length
    let newLength = startingLength + lengthToAdd - lengthToReplace
    return newLength <= charsLimit

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by giving tag to textfield and check that tag inside the fun to identify the textfield uniquely.

Assign `UITextFieldDelegate` to your respective ViewController

set delegate for the textField

```
emailIDTxtFld.delegate = self
mobileNoTxtFld.delegate = self
```

set tag for the textField

```
emailIDTxtFld.tag = 1001
mobileNoTxtFld.tag = 1002
```

Now implement these methods

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    if textField.tag == 1002{
    //For MobileNo it will accept only 10 char
        if newString.characters.count > 10{
            return false
        }else{
            return true
        }
    }else if textField.tag == 1002{
     //your logic
    }
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.tag == 1001{
        if textField.isValidEmail(){
            // Code
        }else{
            print("Please Enter Vlaid Email ID")
        }

    }else if textField.tag == 1002{
        if textField.text?.characters.count == 10{
            // code
        }else{
            //code
        }
}
```